# Parse Google Search with Gson in Java

Tags: java, ajax, json, parsing, gson

I am using Google Search API and it returns a JSON file ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?")

That part is working great. Now I am trying to parse the JSON file and extract the URL from the first result (there could potentially be hundreds of results).

Here is my code:

```
package gson;


import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class GSON {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        try {
            System.out.println("Reading from a JSON file");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/Nic/Desktop/test.json"));

            //Results obj = gson.fromJson(br, Results.class);

            Results results = new Gson().fromJson(br, Results.class);

            for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {
                results.getResults(i);
            }

            //System.out.println("URL: " + obj.getResults());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GSON.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the other class:

```
package gson;

import java.util.List;

public class Results {
    public String url;
    public List<Results> items;

    public String getURL() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setURL(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public List<Results> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setGroups(List<Results> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public void getResults(int i) {
        System.out.println(items.get(i));
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s", url);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
run:
Reading from a JSON file
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gson.Results.getResults(Results.java:26)
    at gson.GSON.main(GSON.java:27)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So `results` is null?

Comment: Yes. It seems that something is off with parsing the JSON and it is not finding the info and adding it to results

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: My bet is that your JSON doesn't match up properly with your `Results` class.  If nothing else, the fact that `Results` contains a list of `Results` (each of which will contain a list of `Results`, each of which will contain a list of `Results`, ad infinitum) worries me.